# Obter diferença em horas com intervalo especifico

Tags: javascript, lógica

Gostaria de obter a diferença em horas entre duas datas com horários, isso é simples, no entanto, no meu exemplo só deve ser considerada as horas das **08:00 até as 16:00**, isso é possível?

Vou postar o código abaixo pra vocês olharem, na minha tela tem um campo para a data e outro para as horas com o minutos, então eu junto esses dois e forma a data com horário no padrão que o javascript consegue realizar os cálculos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Pega a data e converte para mm/dd/yy
  var data1 = new Date($("#data1").val().split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  var horaString1 = $("#hora1").val();
  //Separa o valor em hora e minutos
  var horario1 = horaString1.split(":");

  //Adiciona a hora na data anterior
  data1.setHours(data1.getHours() + horario1[0]);
  //Adiciona os minutos na data anterior
  data1.setMinutes(data1.getMinutes() + horario1[1]);


  //data atual
  var data2 = new Date($("#data2").val().split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  var horaString2 = $("#hora2").val();
  var horario2 = horaString2.split(":");
  data2.setHours(data2.getHours() + horario2[0]);
  data2.setMinutes(data2.getMinutes() + horario2[1]);



  console.log("Data anterior: " + data1)
  console.log("Data atual: " + data2)

  //$("#resultado").val(total);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>Calcular diferença em horas respeitando os intervalors das <b>08:00 ás 16:00</b> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Data Anterior</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data1" value="12/12/2019" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Hora Anterior</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora1" value="09:45" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Data Atual</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data2" value="13/12/2019" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Hora atual</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora2" value="11:30" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Resultado</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resultado" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você tem de checar se as duas datas estão neste intervalo. Você conhece moment.js? Se não quiser implementar.
Você pode limitar os valores máximos nos inputs alterando o tipo do input para time. Checa na doc do Mozilla.

Comment: Já vi algumas pessoas comentando sobre ele, mas nunca cheguei a usar, esse bloqueio nos inputs não é válido pois esses valores não será preenchido pelo o usuário

Comment: @YvesCavalcanti. Você já tem pontos de reputação suficientes para fazer comentários nas perguntas e respostas.